# Preview changes after run project in Idea

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, intellij-idea

I have little issue with my Intellij Idea. When I change chode, for example just add annotation, or edit some function, and run my project (or run debug) these changes are missing. I must stop project and run `mvn clean package`
When I run / debug project again, these changes are reflected. I guess problem is Idea running project from target folder, but it is only my cogitation. Do you have ideas whats is wrong? In project I am using Tomcat 8.5, spring 5, and hibernate 5 if depends on it. Thanks

Comment: The reason the changes are missing is because they are using the previous .class files. When you change the code (add annotation) it needs a recompile. Using maven clean forces you to recompile. It is not a problem. That's standard usage.

Answer (score 0):

Check [**Before launch** options](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-debug-configuration-tomcat-server.html#before_launch_and_share_config) in your Run/Debug Configuration. Make sure you have **Build** step there - that is the instruction for IDE to build your project before launching the Tomcat server and deploy the application.

If you do not use IDE's make you can add `mvn clean package` Maven goal there.